# Printing SSRS does not work on IE 11 of Windows 8 OS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

i badly need your help..

I have a report using SSRS and it is working for lower version of IE browsers except for IE version 11 of Windows 8 OS. I can view my report but I can't print it. No error messages. I have already installed rsclientprint 2008 class but still got no luck. My report is embedded inside an Iframe.

Does anybody know about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have much exp with SSRS in IE11, but make sure IE's security settings aren't set too high.  Printing should prompt you to install an ActiveX control (the first time) so if you're not seeing that prompt you may have your settings too strict.

Comment: I have already set my security settings to the lowest level and i have also enable all options with regard to active x but still got no luck

Comment: My team found that SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 Report Manager did not work properly in IE 11. There were some rendering and printing issues. In order to proceed with the IE 11 deployment, we used what is called IE "Enterprise Mode". We deployed a GPO which tells IE 11 to run our report servers (we listed the URL of each Production and Test Report Manager on the network) with a compatible mode of IE.

Comment: but i think that is time consuming.. my ssrs is embedded inside an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the work around described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2431178